# Outlook365 -- how to properly quote incoming email in response?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, office365

When I use the method below , and select 3 paragraphs and choose Quote, I get a response that includes the 3 paragraphs quoted.

But I cannot figure out how to unquote my response under each paragraph. How do I unquote lines to get my response in there?

[image]

**UPDATE STATUS (Feb 2020)**

I dumped Outlook entirely, and have been much happier since.

Comment: +1 for dumping Outlook (and other "mind draining" tools).